# Is it possible to feed packer with an ansible encrypted file?

Tags: ansible, packer, hashicorp-packer

I'm attempting to use packer from an ansible playbook in order to use an ansible-vault encrypted file in the build process.

Specifically, I have an "autounnattend.xml" answer file for automated windows. I'd like to encrypt this file with ansible-vault encrypt, and then use this file in a packer template, that looks like this:

```
source "vsphere-iso" "windows" {
  # truncated for brevity
  floppy_files          = [
  "[insert DEcrypted autounnattend.xml file here]",
  "./scripts/winrm.bat",
  "./scripts/Install-VMWareTools.ps1",
  "./drivers/"
  ]
}
```

Is this possible?
Or is there a different way, I can use run-time decrypted files in my packer build?

Comment: Use the [`file` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_lookup.html).

Comment: The file lookup is an ansible processor, and it loads the file contents into a variable, so I either have to find a way to get packer to accept the file contents as a variable instead of a filepath, or I can't use the ansible file lookup, but I can't find an equivalent for packer - that also is able to use the decrypted file

Comment: You might be interested in the following collection I made as a test to answer an other question: https://github.com/ansible-ThoTeam/thoteam.var_as_file

Comment: We need to see the Ansible `provisioner` block in the Packer template.

Comment: It's possible to use Packer with an Ansible Vault-file.  You could for instance add `"ansible_env_vars": [ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE=]` to the Ansible provisioner, but please add your whole `*.json` template for packer.

Comment: I'm using it "the other way around". I'm starting my packer build with ansible. The provisioner in packer would run AFTER the build process, which is too late to use the autounattend.xml for the windows installation.